# Installed Plotly in the same environment but when trying to import plotly.express, jupyter shows error : Module not found Error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, conda, modulenotfounderror, plotly-express

[Showing Error - No Module named 'plotly'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldfiC.png)

[Python already installed as well as plotly upgraded to the latest version in the same environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJlLa.png)

Plotly is installed in the same folder but still shows this error of module not found when I'm trying to import plotly.express

1. Have tried and installed anaconda navigator.
2. Installed plotly using the command: 'conda install -c plotly plotly=4.8.1'.
3. Upgraded the version of plotly to the latest.

Comment: First decide what you are using. In your troubleshooting list, you list `Have tried and installed anaconda navigator.` If you are going to be using Jupyter inside that, from now on you want to always use Anaconda/conda as your package manager. Which by number two you are fine with. So according to [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/), **inside your notebook where you want to use plotly**, you'd run in a new cell `%conda install -c plotly plotly=5.14.0`. (NOTE THE MAGIC COMMAND.) Let that install and then restart the kernel and now try your `import` statement for plotly express.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the active notebook.